# If a matrix's eigenvalues are all $1$, is the matrix the identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's that time of night when my girl and I bicker about matrices. Tonight we ponder whether a square matrix of dimension $d$ which has a spectrum of $1$'s with multiplicity $d$ must be $I$.

If such a matrix is diagonalizable, then it must be $I$. But we're not sure what would happen if it is not diagonalizable or whether that is even a possibility.

Relatedly, we're having a tough time thinking up a matrix other than $I$ whose spectrum is all $1$'s.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Aha! Thank you.

Comment: So I infer that to be $I$, the matrix must be diagonalizable then..?

Comment: You already said (correctly) in the question: _If such a matrix is diagonalizable, then it must be $I$._

Comment: Extending the example of @gniourf_gniourf, it is the whole theory of Jordan forms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form that you should have a look at.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. This is great!

Comment: Would be nice to describe those that are not diagonalizable...  what special properties do they have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To close the question, I'll answer referring to gniourf_gniourf's comments.

**No. If the eigenvalues of a matrix are all $1$, then the matrix need not be the identity.**

Counterexample: $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

**If the eigenvalues of a matrix are all $1$ *and* it is diagonalizable, then it is the identity.**

Comment: very interesting but i have one question: how is it possible that there exists an eigendecomposition (which I computed in Matlab with [V,D]=eig([1 1;0 1]), yet V*D*inv(V) seems impossible as V is not invertible (determinant = 0) ... so I just realized that diagonalizable is not exacly the same as eigen-decomposable ... could you give me some insights?

Comment: I mean I though that being eigen-decomposable implied being diagonalizable but obviously my knowlege about that is limited

Comment: @SheppLogan Non-diagonalizable matrices require a relaxed definition of eigenvectors, called generalized eigenvectors. I think this is what MATLAB's eig function returns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector